# Sending Email with Attachments in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-boot

I'm trying to send an email with file attachments in Spring Boot.

This is a basic gmail SMTP server application properties config:

This is my EmailService:

```
EmailService
```

When I call this method with mailMessageDto object passed, there is no exception thrown. Nothing happens, e-mail isn't sent.

I have debugged on javaMailSender.send(messsage) line of code and everything seems fine.

**Update**

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=false
```

should be false not true spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you to apply [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) to `sendMessageWithAttachment()` method by extracting functionality around adding attachments:

```java
private void addAttachments(MailMessageDto message, MimeMessageHelper helper) {
  message.getFiles().forEach(file -> addAttachment(file, helper));
}
```

This method [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) over all files and adds every file by using `addAttachment()`:

```java
private void addAttachment(File file, MimeMessageHelper helper) {
  String fileName = file.getName();
  try {
    helper.addAttachment(fileName, file);
    log.debug("Added a file atachment: {}", fileName);
  } catch (MessagingException ex) {
    log.error("Failed to add a file atachment: {}", fileName, ex);
  }
}
```

This will log an error for each failed attachment. Can you try this approach?

Comment: Also I'm sending a fileDataSource instead of just a file. And it's not working with this approach.

Comment: @FrankLabry why can't you call [getFile()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/activation/FileDataSource.html#getFile()) method? Also it means your approach [will not work](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java.activation-summary.html) in [Java 11](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html#JDK-8190378) without software changes.

Comment: the problem is that I'm retrieving multipartFiles from RestController on my client side. You have to, however, send them from the server side as FileSystemResource in that case, not only as a File. I have written the name of it wrong in the previous comment.

Comment: @FrankLabry ok, so why not [FileSystemResource.getFile()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html#getFile--)?

Answer (score 5):

step 1. add dependencies in porm.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

step 2. add configuration code in application.properties

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.username=username
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.protocol=smtps
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

step 3. add code in controller
masterconroller.java

```
@GetMapping("/sendmail")
@ResponseBody
String home() {
    try {
        masterServiceImpl.sendEmail("path");
        return "Email Sent!";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return "Error in sending email: " + ex;
    }
}
```

step 4. add code in MasterServiceImpl.java

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
public void sendEmail(String path) throws Exception{
         MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
         MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
         helper.setTo("xyz@gmail.com");
         helper.setText("<html><body><h1>hello Welcome!</h1><body></html>", true);
         FileSystemResource file  = new FileSystemResource(new File(path));
         helper.addAttachment("testfile", file);
         helper.addAttachment("test.png", new ClassPathResource("test.jpeg"));
         helper.setSubject("Hi");
         javaMailSender.send(message);
   }
```